Does every door space with an infinite compact set have a single non-isolated point?
A door space has the property that every subset is either closed or open.
Note that discrete spaces are door spaces (every subset is both closed and open).
A simple non-discrete space that is a door space would be a converging sequence: a set either misses the limit point and is open, or contains the limit point and is closed. Note that the limit point is the only non-isolated point, and this is an infinite compact space.
Another door space example is a particular point topology: a set either contains the particular point and is open, or misses the particular point and is closed. Note that no point except the particular point is isolated, and every compact subspace is finite (that is, the space is anticompact).
Does it hold that every door space that contains an infinite compact subspace must have a single non-isolated point?

Yes, this is true. 
Let $X$ be a topological space.
We need the following definitions:

$I(X)$ is the set of isolated points of $X$.
$\mathcal F = \{A \subset I(X): X \setminus I(X) \subset \overline{A}\}$.
$X$ is weakly cid, if each countable, infinite subset of $X$ contains an infinite subset which is closed in $X$.

[Of course, if each countable subset of $X$ is closed, then
$X$ is weakly cid. Since spaces with this property are sometimes called cid, I choose weakly cid for the above.]
Lemma 1.
Let $X$ be $T_1$ and weakly cid. Then each infinite subset of $X$ contains an infinite, discrete, closed (in $X$) subset.
In particular, each compact subset is finite.
PROOF.
The first part is proved in this paper by G. Gruenhage, Theorem 0.1. (b). (Although stated differently, all, what is used in the proof, is weakly cid and $T_1$.)
The second part is then obvious.
Lemma 2.
Let $X$ be door space.

If $I(X)$ is finite, then $X$ is weakly cid.
If $\emptyset \neq X$ is compact, then $I(X) \neq \emptyset$.

PROOF.
1.
Let $A$ be a countable, infinite subset of $X$.
Assume, each infinite subset of $A$ is open in $X$.
Then $A$ itself is open.
Moreover, it is easy to see that $A$ is discrete.
Hence, $A \subset I(X)$. Contradiction.
Hence, $A$ contains an infinite, non-open, thus closed, subspace.
 2.
Assume, $I(X) = \emptyset$. Then X is $T_1$.
Hence, by lemma 1, $X$ is finite. Hence, $X$ is discrete.
Remark.
Lemma 2.2 is all, what we will need from the above.
Perhaps this can also be proven without weakly cid and Lemma 1?
Lemma 3.
If $X$ is door space, then $I(X)$ is closed or dense in $X$.
PROOF.
If $I(X)$ is not dense, pick $x \in X \setminus \overline{I(X)}$. 
Assume, $I(X) \cup \{x\}$ is open. Then
$\{x\} = (I(X) \cup \{x\}) \cap (X \setminus \overline{I(X)})$ is open in $X \setminus \overline{I(X)}$. Hence, $x \in I(X)$. Contradiction.

Thus, $I(X) \cup \{x\}$ is closed.
Hence, $\overline{I(X)} \subset I(X) \cup \{x\}$,
hence, $\overline{I(X)} \subset I(X)$.
Lemma 4.
Let X be infinite, compact and door space.
Then $I(X)$ is dense in $X$.
PROOF.
Assume, not. Then, by lemma 3,
$X \setminus I(X)$ is open. Hence,
$I(X \setminus I(X)) = \emptyset$.
Of course, $X \setminus I(X)$ is compact, door.
Hence, by lemma 2, $X = I(X)$.
Lemma 5.
Let X be door space, $\overline{I(X)} = X$ and $|X \setminus I(X)| \ge 2$.

If $A \subset I(X)$, then the following are equivalent:

(i) $\overline{A} \cap (X \setminus I(X)) \neq 
       \emptyset$ 
(ii) $A \in \mathcal F$ 
(iii) $A \cup \{x\}$ is open in $X$
for all $x \in X \setminus I(X)$. 
(iv) $A \cup \{x\}$ is open in $X$
for some $x \in X \setminus I(X)$.

$\mathcal F$ is an ultrafilter on $I(X)$
(not necessarily free!)

$X \setminus I(X)$ is closed, discrete.


PROOF.

We will frequently use that
$X = \overline{I(X)} = \overline{A} \cup \overline{I(X)\setminus A}$.

(i) $\Rightarrow$ (ii):
Pick $x_0 \in \overline{A} \cap (X \setminus I(X))$.
Let $x \in X \setminus I(X)$ and assume $x \notin \overline{A}$.
Then $x \in \overline{I(X)\setminus A} \subset
   \overline{(I(X)\setminus A) \cup \{x_0\}}$.
Hence, $(I(X)\setminus A) \cup \{x_0\}$ is open.
Hence, $\emptyset \neq ((I(X)\setminus A) \cup \{x_0\})
\cap A$. Contradiction!

(ii) $\Rightarrow$ (iii):
Let $x \in X \setminus I(X)$. Assume, $A \cup \{x\}$ is not open, then it is closed.
By the assumption, pick $y \in X \setminus I(X), y \neq x$.
Then $y \in \overline{A} \subset A \cup \{x\}$. Contradiction!

(iii) $\Rightarrow$ (iv) nothing to prove here.

(iv) $\Rightarrow$ (i):
Pick $x \in X \setminus I(X)$ with $A \cup \{x\}$ open.
Assume, $x \notin \overline{A}$.
Then $x \in \overline{I(X) \setminus A}$.
Hence, $\emptyset \neq (A \cup \{x\}) \cap  (I(X) \setminus A)$. Contradiction.

Obviously, $\emptyset \notin \mathcal F$ and
for $A \in \mathcal F, A \subset B \subset I(X)$, it is
$B \in \mathcal F$.
If $A, B \in \mathcal F$, then by 1.(iii), $A \cap B \in \mathcal F$.

Let $A \subset I(X)$. Pick $x \in X \setminus I(X)$.
Then $x \in \overline{A}$ or $x \in \overline{I(X) \setminus A}$. Hence, by 1., $A \in \mathcal F$ or
$I(X) \setminus A \in \mathcal F$.

By 1., $I(X) \cup \{x\}$ is open in $X$
for all $x \in X \setminus I(X)$.
Hence, $X \setminus I(X)$ is discrete.
Of course, it is closed.

Theorem.
Let $X$ be an infinite, compact door space.
Then $X$ contains exactly one non-isolated point.
PROOF.
$X$ cannot be discrete, thus it contains at least one non-isolated point.
By lemma 4, $\overline{I(X)} = X$.

Assume now, $|X \setminus I(X)| \ge 2$.
By lemma 5, $X \setminus I(X)$ is finite. Hence, $I(X)$ is infinite.
Since $\mathcal F$ is an ultrafilter on $I(X)$, there exists an
$A \in \mathcal F$ such that $I(X) \setminus A$ is infinite.
By lemma 5,
$\{A \cup (X \setminus I(X))\} \cup \{\{x\}: x \in I(X) \setminus A\}$ is an open cover of $X$ without a finite subcover. Contradiction.
Corollary.
Let $X$ be a door space,
which contains an infinite, compact subspace.
Then $X$ contains exactly one non-isolated point.
PROOF.
As above, $X$ contains at least one non-isolated point.

Now, let $A$ be the infinite, compact subspace.
Then, by the theorem, $A$ contains exactly one non-isolated
point $a$ and it is $a \in \overline{A \setminus \{a\}}$.
Let $a \neq x \in X$.
Then $B := A \cup \{x\}$ is infinite, compact, door space.
Obviously, $a \in B \setminus I(B)$.
Hence, again by the theorem, $x \in I(B)$.
$(A \setminus \{a\}) \cup \{x\}$ is not closed, hence open in $X$. It follows $x \in I(X)$.
Thus, $a$ is the unique non-isolated point in $X$.

Thanks for this work. It certainly seems to be a more involved question than I expected!

For reference, one paper about "cid": https://zbmath.org/0665.54003

Fixed the definition of weakly cid (see https://beaconpointservices.org/commas-with-relative-clauses-which-that-who/) so the meaning is correct.  Hope you don't mind.

I think someone asked in the Pitt(?) topology seminar recently if "countable sets are closed" had a name, so I appreciate that lead as well!

Hmm wait, that paper defines "cid" to mean countable sets are discrete?

@Steven Clontz: this is the same: it is easy to see that each countable subset is discrete, if and only if each countable subset is closed.

@PatrickR: no, I don't mind about deleting a comma -;) Thank you for the correction. I'm just wondering: what do you mean by "meaning is correct"? I.e., what would be the meaning with the comma? BTW, I'm sure I will not remember. So, I hope, you don't mind, if I do it wrongly next time again. And, of course, feel free to correct it again.

Got it! Countable sets are closed => all subsets of a countable subset are closed => countable sets are discrete. Countable sets are discrete => given a point outside the set, including it gives a new countable discrete set => each point outside the set is not in the closure => countable sets are closed.

@Ulli the meaning with the comma was "cid = each countable infinite subset of $X$ contains an infinite subset, and by the way, any such subset must be closed".  Of course that does not make much sense unless one interprets it as intended.  So in this case, ignoring the comma is the only thing that makes sense.  Commas are used differently in German? maybe.  Not using the comma where it should not be (i.e. for "restrictive clauses") would really help the understanding.  It's all over the place; e.g., in the last Corollary ("door space which"), etc, etc.

Just to clarify again, the last Corollary with the comma has the implied meaning of "Let $X$ be a door space.  And as an aside, because it's a door space, it must contain an infinite compact subspace."  Without the comma, the meaning is "Let $X$ be a door space of a specific kind, namely ..." See https://beaconpointservices.org/commas-with-relative-clauses-which-that-who/
